# Convert date string to Datetime Python Format Error

Tags: python, datetime

I know there are a lot of answers to this question online, but none of them have worked for me. I am trying to convert a date string into a Datetime object, of the following format: yyyy-mm-dd

My `date_string` is '2017-02-02T00:00:00Z'

I am trying to convert it by doing `date_value = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d')` but I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: time data '"2017-02-02T00:00:00Z"' does not match format
> '%Y%m%d'

Also, should I be worried about the double quotes around my `date_string` string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date) -> esp. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418 ;-)

Comment: Your date/time string pattern is incorrect. It doesn't account for the time component at all.

Comment: @MrFuppes Thank you for the link. I have tried the suggestion `date = datetime.fromisoformat("2017-02-02T00:00:00.Z")` but I get an error `ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '"2017-02-02T00:00:00.Z"'`

Comment: Did you check out the second link in my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument in the method `strptime` is the pattern of your string.

Here is the full list of available code formats. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

All the remaining "non-informative" characters in your string can simply be put as-is in there correct places.

Thanks to @MrFuppes for this info: you should also parse the trailing "Z" as `%z`. This will signal python that it's a UTC datetime and not a local datetime.

Your code should be :

```
date_string = '2017-02-02T00:00:00Z'
date_value = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

As for the extra quotes, that's not wanted. You should try this beforehand :

```
date_string = date_string.strip("'").strip('"')
```

If `strip()` didn't work, you can call `eval` instead (usually not recommended) :

```
date_string = eval(date_string)
```

Comment: `Z` should not be parsed with a literal "Z" in the parsing directive. Why? This results in naive datetime, which Python treats as *local time*, while Z signals UTC. And secondly, using `eval` for something that can be done with a simple `replace` is inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the informative Z. Although `replace` is less appropriate than `strip` IMO, I agree with you about `eval`.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I've tried the same sequence as you but I'm still getting a similar error (even after stripping the quotes): `ValueError: time data '"2017-02-02T00:00:00Z"' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'`

Comment: That's because the character (quote or doublequote) you're trying to remove should be the inner one shown in the Exception. So it would be `.strip('"')`. You can actually chain the `strip` method to handle both cases. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! There was another slight issue with regards to comparing "offset-naive" and "offset-aware" which threw an error, but otherwise this works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to parse your *date_string* first, and that should help. Using *strptime()* right away on an unparsed datetime string can sometimes cause problems. Also you shouldn't worry about your double quotes, it's fine.

First, install the *python-dateutil* library if you haven't already (**pip install python-dateutil** at the command line). Then test the solution with the following code.

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

date_string = '2017-02-02T00:00:00Z'

#we parse the string, it becomes a datetime object
parsed_date_string = dateutil.parser.parse(date_string)
print(parsed_date_string)

#output looks like this: 2017-02-02 00:00:00+00:00

#now your statement will work
date_value = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(parsed_date_string), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
print(date_value)

#output will also be: 2017-02-02 00:00:00+00:00
```

The *strptime()* statement worked this time because we parsed our date first with *parse()*. Note also that to use *strptime()* we need to cast our *parsed_date_string* back to a string because *parse()* converts our original string to an object of class *datetime.datetime* and *strptime()* is expecting a string.

Hopefully that helped.